# is it possible to auto refresh alert without closing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to refresh v-alert automatically after 1 sec without closing it so that value store in locaStorage can be reflected on v-alert after every 1 sec.

```
<v-alert
    style="position: fixed;left: 35%;top: 7%;"
      border="left"
      close-text="Close Alert"
      color="deep-purple accent-4"
      dark
      dismissible
      text-align ='center'
      v-model="alert"
    >
      Yesterday's Leads: {{this.totalAndYetToCallCounts.previousLeads}} and Today's Leads: {{this.totalAndYetToCallCounts.TodaysLeads}}.
    </v-alert>
```

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      totalAndYetToCallCounts: '',
      alert: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    alert (newVal) {
      if (!newVal) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.alert = true
          this.totalAndYetToCallCounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getTotalAndYetToCallCount'))
        }, 1000)
      }
    }

  },
}
```

after writing it in created hook

```
  async created () {
    try {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.alert = true
        this.totalAndYetToCallCounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getTotalAndYetToCallCount'))
      }, 1000)

  },
```

Comment: using the `dismissable` prop allows users to close the v-alert manually. your watcher only activates when `alert` changes, meaning the user **must** close v-alert for the watcher to run, update the strings, and immediately reopen the v-alert... I don't see why you don't just remove `dismissable` which will let v-alert remain displayed forever.  then you just need to concentrate on updating the string variables every 1 second.  v-alert will take care of itself.

Comment: @yoduh I need dismissable as well. So the situation is like When alert is closed it needs to be reopen after few seconds and I also need to update value on alert after evey 1 sec which is coming from localStorage.

Comment: your strings like `this.totalAndYetToCallCounts.previousLeads` should be reactive, so no matter how/where/when you update them, they'll automatically and immediately update on the UI in your v-alert.  instead of updating them in a watcher, which only runs after the user dismisses v-alert, use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) in your created or mounted hook to update the strings which would be independent of v-alerts display status.

Comment: @yoduh but if I removed from watch and place it in created hook, then on close of alert will it again appear after few second?

Comment: you can keep the watcher just to set `this.alert = true` which will reopen the v-alert but move the text updating to somewhere else

Comment: async created () {
    try {
          alert (newVal) {
      if (!newVal) {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.alert = true
          this.totalAndYetToCallCounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getTotalAndYetToCallCount'))
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  },

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ";" -> error coming up when tried to write in created hook. Above is the code. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251044/discussion-between-kiran-and-yoduh).

Comment: please post new code into your question as snippets as its easier to read there.  I can tell you already though that using the same exact code from your watcher, which requires a specific syntax, and pasting it in `created()` is not going to work.  you should only have the setInterval inside `created`, the surrounding code doesn't make sense to keep.

Comment: @yoduh but when I close same timer is used which is used in setInterval. I have added my code as snippets. setInterval should set after every 1 sec but when I close alert it should again popup after 10mins. This is what I am trying to do. Now setInterval is working fine but currently after closing popup again gets open in 1 sec

Comment: Issue is resolved. I added watcher and setTimeout to 10 mins and from created hook removed this.alert = true. Now it is working perfectly fine. Thank you so much for help